# Get path to image 

Tags: javascript, html, relative-path

I wrote a javascript method to display an image dynamically depending on whether or not a plugin is installed or not. Depending on the page, the url might be deep into sub paths and i wanted to see if i can get a path back to the image without all the marky-mark.

**Example**

myImage src location = {root}/Content/Images/myImage.png

Now call the js to display the image on the following pages. I show the path of the example page and the image element with the src path. Notice how its different depending on how deep we are. If i use an absolute path, then i would have to change it for my test environment and production. I thought I could use ~ but i guess not. Ideas ?

http://mysite.com/sub1/sub2/ -- `<img src="../../Content/Images/myImage.png" />`

http://localhost:2500/sub1/ -- `<img src="../Content/Images/myImage.png" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde is only relevant for .NET server side code.

An easy way to accomplish what you're looking for is to write the root path out to a javascript variable or function.

For example on the server side on your page:

```
public string RootPath
{
  get
  {
     return ResolveUrl("~/");
  }
}
```

And then use the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getRoot()
{
   return '<%= RootPath %>';
}
// -->
</script>
```

You can then use the javascript getRoot function to get to the root of the website and use it for your urls.

Comment: Should this work then ?

<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/myImage.png") %>

Comment: Possibly, I'd have to see it in context, but you're probably on the right path. Something similar to what you're trying to do that's usuing Url.Content is available at http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/jquery-ui-tabs-and-aspnet-mvc/. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I am using asp.net MVC... and when I use the Url.Content, it doesnt work actually. Here's what I have to test it ... alert('<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/myImage.png") %>');

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the asp.net MVC framework, but this url might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx. For example, you should be able to use Request.ApplicationPath or something similar to get you that root path you need.